# matplotlib FuncAnimation issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm currently trying to display dynamically the result of a genetic fitting I'm running (so that I can decide when to stop). The code is pretty much the following:

```
#vars stands for a bunch of variables required for the simulation and the fit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class plotSim:
    def __init__(self, vars, line)
        self.vars = vars
        self.line = line

    def animate(self,i):
        simulation_fit_result = perform_simulation_fit(self.vars)
        self.line.set_ydata(simulation_fit_result)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,8))
ax.semilogy(x_experimental,y_experimental)
line, = ax.semilogy(x_simulation,y_simulation) #initializing the line with the simulation performed with the initial values to fit

plotfit = plotSim(vars,line)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plotfit.animate,interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

I can't see the difference with other example I found googling. In my case the simulation is successfully performed (as I can see some stuff printed I placed for check) but no figures are showing (not even a static one). I also had the same problem using plt.ion() combined with plt.draw(). I'm using Spyder 2.1.9 IDE under Ubuntu 12.04, can this have any influence?

Thanks for the help to anyone answering.

Comment: Can you make the example runnable? Dummy data is fine, I just want something I can test.

Comment: Your animate function does not depend on `i`, every pass through it draws the same thing.